How to retrieve user's data from Google user?
Help , I want retrieve Google email into JSON type or HTML but I cant do this , even I create new session and get from gothic.Store but this error appear :
Error:"Error when create new session in GoogleController securecookie: the value is not valid
Here is my function to store session :
var store = sessions.NewCookieStore(
    securecookie.GenerateRandomKey(32), // Encryption key
    securecookie.GenerateRandomKey(32), // Authentication key
)

func InitSecureSession() {
    // ... existing code ...
    gothic.Store = store
}


CallBack to result(/success) :
provider := ctx.Param("provider")
    q := ctx.Request.URL.Query()

    q.Add("provider", provider)
    ctx.Request.URL.RawQuery = q.Encode()

    user, err := gothic.CompleteUserAuth(ctx.Writer, ctx.Request)
    if err != nil {
        ctx.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
            "Error": "Error when callback in GoogleController " + err.Error(),
        })
        return
    }

    session, err := gothic.Store.New(ctx.Request, "Login")
    if err != nil {
        ctx.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
            "Error": "Error when create new session in GoogleController " + err.Error(),
        })
        return
    }
    session.Values["user"] = user
    session.Save(ctx.Request, ctx.Writer)

    ctx.Redirect(http.StatusTemporaryRedirect, "/success")

And here is show result :
session, err := gothic.Store.Get(c.Request, "Login")
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"error": "Failed to get session"})
        return
    }

    user, ok := session.Values["user"].(goth.User)
    if !ok {
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"error": "User not found in session"})
        return
    }

    index, err := template.ParseFiles("View/Success.html")
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
            "Error": "Error at Success " + err.Error(),
        })
        c.Abort()
        return
    }

    err = index.Execute(c.Writer, gin.H{
        "user": user,
    })
    c.JSON(200, gin.H{
        "User": user,
    })
    if err != nil {
        c.AbortWithStatus(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

File Success.html to show my expected result :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>It's ok kichana</h1>
    <p>Email: {{.email}}</p>
<a href="/logout">Logout</a>
    
</body>
</html>

I don't know why the securecookie isn't valid ? Am I forget to something ?
I'm getting tired with handling sessions ‍♂️
